# RDP not allowing me to remote to any user?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control, remote-assistance

I have a computer several actually that will allow me to RDP remote log into that PC but only under the admin account and not the other?

For example the PC has two admins one might be Admin with the password as qwerty and the other user might be Jacob with a password of qwerty12 just as an example. I can only log into Admin I get an Error saying my credentials didn’t work when trying to log into Jacob.

Any suggestion or Ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Is RDP enabled and allowed in "Jacobs" profile/account?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Super User is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, so please don't post responses to answers as answers. It appears you're using a different computer or web browser now than you did before. Try registering on the site so the site will allow you to comment on answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually permit other users to log in via remote desktop:

[image]

1. Go to System Control Panel
2. Go to remote Settings
3. Click "Select Users"
4. Click "Add"
5. Add the user account for `jacob`

OK to all those screens and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jacob , from your example, is not included in the server's user group membership.

Try giving Jacob user permission to connect. It must be on the list of users.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out it is a win7 issue when changing a username it doesnt completley change everything I have to go in rename the user folder c:\User and then edit a regestry for the new name to actually take. Thanks yall